# How to set nomodeset on RHEL 5?

Tags: linux, rhel, grub, nomodeset

I've installed RHEL v5 on my PC. The installation was successful, but after that I came across 2 lines on boot-up, the first one was `setting clock with OK message` and the second one was `starting udev with OK message`. After that a black screen showed up. I searched the internet and came to know that the systems which do have integrated graphics card will not load during boot-up, so the solution I found was to do the `nomodeset` option on GRUB, but I am very new to Linux so I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In /boot/grub/grub.conf, add `nomodeset` on each indented line starting "kernel".

Jaroslav's answer sorts you out into booting into your box, my answer above makes it permanent.

Answer (score 1):

It's kernel parameter so when you're in the grub on your selected kernel, press 'e' for editing. Go to the second line which begins with 'kernel /vmlinuz...' and pres 'e' again. You can add the nomodeset to to end of the line. All params are delimited by spaces.

When it boots up and you finaly get to the system, open the /etc/grub.conf and append the parameter to the similar line(s), you've just edited interactively. This makes the change permanent.